# How to detect circular tap with UITouch?

Tags: ios, xcode

How to detect a circular tap with UITouch in iOS?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
  // what goes here?
}
```

Comment: do u mean to say circular drag ?

Comment: yes i mean circular "drag". All i want is a circular motion detection   around an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is some kind of way to detect a circular movement. I suggest you look into `UIGestureRecognizer`. If so then perhaps this can help you, it's a `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass for this purpose.

I used this in an application where I wanted to add the ability to turn a round switch around, a bit like a volume control on a Hi-Fi system. Check it out.

https://bitbucket.org/danielphillips/dpcirculargesturerecognizer